# CSS Same Height for Tabbed Sections

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, flexbox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Please note the following HTML for a Tabbed display (for an option page):
I would like to maintain the same height as tab1 for tab2 and tab3

```
<article>
  <nav> <!-- content --> </nav>
  <section id="tab1"> <!-- content --> </section>
  <section id="tab2"><iframe src=""></iframe></section>
  <section id="tab3"><iframe src=""></iframe></section>
</article>
```

- tab1 always loads first with `display: block;` and both tab2 & tab3
  have  `display: none;`
- tab1 has variable content, so it is not practical to set a fixed `height` or `min-height`
- Setting `display: flex;` on  `article` interferes with `nav`
- Setting `display: flex;` also interferes with `display: none;`
- `nav` can not be moved to outside `article`
- Both tab2 & tab3 display with shorter height which results in unsightly resizing of the overall box

**N.B.** *The HTML is used in a Firefox/Chrome Extension's Options page, and NOT a web page. Since Chrome uses Panels and Firefox uses Options page, Pixel based solutions might not work as expected. There might also be Firefox/Chrome specific solutions.*

Comment: How does `display: flex` interfere with `nav` and `display: none`?

Comment: Removed extension tags, as this is not at all specific to extensions.

Comment: @Xan .. there was a reason for that. Chrome displays extension options (panel) differently than Firefox (options page) so suggestions using px would not work.Furthermore, there might be browser specific solutions such as -moz etc

Comment: I don't see that explained in the question, though. If you can justify it, feel free to edit the tags back.

Comment: @Xan .. the question stated "for an option page" and then tagged Firefox/Chrome browser which should have made it obvious.

Comment: _"Chrome displays extension options (panel) differently than Firefox (options page) so suggestions using px would not work."_ It would be helpful to indicate it in the question. _"Furthermore, there might be browser specific solutions such as -moz etc"_ The question does not state you are looking for those. In short: you're not that limited in the question size, don't put too much semantic meaning into tags.

Comment: In addition to my first comment, is your `nav` sized by content or can you give it a height?

Comment: Third question, do you know if you can use viewport units in those extensions?

Comment: @LGSon .. using flex causes the nav to stretch vertically and creates  2 columns with nav & tab1 instead of 2 rows. All sections start as display: none and only the active tab then turned to display block. The height of the nav is no relevant since it can vary so a fixed size will not work. I haven't tried viewport.

Comment: Okay, would this be an option? (and pay attention to my comments in markup) ... https://jsfiddle.net/d4d6zrp2/7/

Comment: @LGSon .. wow. some fancy CSS work... looks good on jsfiddle. Let me test it in the actual situation and report back.

Comment: @LGSon .. it works on both Firefox & Chrome Options pages. I added a 4th dummy section in order to get round figure for translateX(-25%). While it is a totally different approach to what I had in mind, it is a good approach. Please post it and I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: PS. width: 400%; as well (I couldn't edit my comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have dynamic equal height elements without script, you could use CSS Flexbox.

Here I added a couple of `input`'s and `label`'s to do the actual tabbing, and an extra `div` as a wrapper for the `section`'s.

By setting `overflow: hidden` on the `article`, give the `div` the size times amount of `section`'s, one can simply slide it back and forth, sideways, to achieve your requirements.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d4d6zrp2/8/)

*Here done as a Stack snippet with a twist, animated the slide and, as commented, with 4 sections*

```css
article {
  overflow: hidden;
}

article > input {
  display: none;
}

article nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

article nav label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

article > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 400%;
  transition: transform 1s;           /* added to animate the slide */
}

article section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
}

article input[id="tab1"]:checked ~ div {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

article input[id="tab2"]:checked ~ div {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

article input[id="tab3"]:checked ~ div {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

article input[id="tab4"]:checked ~ div {
  transform: translateX(-75%);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <!-- added inputs and labels for this demo -->
  <input type="radio" name="radiotabs" id="tab1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="radiotabs" id="tab2">
  <input type="radio" name="radiotabs" id="tab3">
  <input type="radio" name="radiotabs" id="tab4">
  
  <nav>
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
    <label for="tab4">Tab 4</label>
  </nav>

  <!-- this extra wapper is needed to solve this without script -->
  <div>
    <section id="stab1">
      Section 1
    </section>
    <section id="stab2">
      Section 2
      <br>this has more content
      <br>this has more content
      <br>this has more content
    </section>
    <section id="stab3">
      Section 3
    </section>
    <section id="stab4">
      Section 4
    </section>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Just for Info... I added a dummy 4th section with no navigation, content or even css, purely so that I get 25% -50% etc instead of 33.333333% ie `<section><!-- Just for layout --></section>`. ;)

Comment: @erosman How you wish :) ... thanks ... and updated the fiddle demo with that extra section for layout only

Comment: lol.. you added animation too... I had added it myself as well :D

Comment: I had opacity transition before. I am having trouble combining it with the current transform. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @erosman You want it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/d4d6zrp2/9/ ... or with both? https://jsfiddle.net/d4d6zrp2/10/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily with a bit of jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $(".div1").height("auto");
    $(".div2").height("auto");
    $(".div3").height("auto");
    var height = Math.max($(".div1").outerHeight(), $(".div2").outerHeight(), $(".div3").outerHeight());
    $(".div1").height(height);
    $(".div2").height(height);
    $(".div3").height(height);
  }).resize();
});
```

The variable `height` will be highest height of any of the 3 elements and then you apply it to all 3.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e4gvojzm/)**

I added the "resize" function to make it work if user resizes the window as the height may change while doing it.

Comment: Thank you but that seems like a JavaScript solution (and JQuery code). I was hoping for CSS solution. Furthermore, 2 of the elements have display none which may not work as in your code that deals with displayed elements.

Comment: Only css solution is flex.and you don't want to use it.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without flex or JS. One possibility is to instead of display: none using visibility: hidden cause then the element stays rendered and takes up the space it's just not visible and if they have the same background then you would get the "illusion" as they would be the same height. But this again means changing how the tabs behave with JS... or maybe not.... Maybe you can override the default classes styling.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez .. it is not that I DON'T want to use it. Show me a way to use it to achieve the desired result and I will.

Comment: @nejc.m visibility: hidden will result in an even more unsightly display as it would create a page 3 times longer than each tab. Please note that this is a tabbed display so only one section should be visible at a time.

Comment: Man. We are trying to help. If you say nav interferes with flex... At the very least show us an example so we can see the prob. If possible without shouting or demanding... I don't think you are paying me a salary so I have to tolerate your rudeness. Still I dont get why you cant implement an easy jquery solution. It's 2017. All webs use Javascript.

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution to a question that is not tagged with jQuery is often not helpful. If the OP wanted a jQuery based solution, they could have/should have tagged the question with jQuery, or mentioned it in the question. In fact, the [javascript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) explicitly states: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Comment: At a minimum, you should be combining your selectors, so you only have to do one search through the DOM (e.g. `$('.div1,.div2,.div3).height()`). Alternately, if you are going to be performing multiple operations on the same element(s) (or jQuery Object), then store it in a variable, don't repeatedly do the same DOM query just to get the same element(s). DOM query's are massively more expensive than using a variable.